# automating downloading a .iqy file and reading the data from it

Tags: r, excel-web-query

I've a link where I need to download data which is in ".iqy" file and I need to read that for further cleaning.

I'm able to do it manually by entering the link present(in 3rd line) in the file using

`con <- file("ABC1.iqy", "r", blocking = FALSE)
   readLines(con=con,n=-1L,ok=TRUE, warn=FALSE,encoding='unknown').`

Output:

```
[1] "WEB"
[2] "1"
[3] "https:abc.../excel/execution/EPnx?view=vrs" [4] ""
[5] ""
[6] "Selection=AllTables"
[7] "Formatting=None"
[8] "PreFormattedTextToColumns=True"
[9] "ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True"
[10] "SingleBlockTextImport=False"
[11] "DisableDateRecognition=False"
[12] "DisableRedirections=False"
[13] ""
```

I need to automate this instead of doing it manually. Is there any option in r that I can use?

Comment: @Moddy_Mudskipper: ya.. :) I just got it right. Also your code works however it pulls it all in a single column like this 
        <table>
    <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
        <th>column3</th>
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `download.file` :)

```
con <- file("ABC1.iqy", "r", blocking = FALSE)
dest_path <- "ABC.file"
download.file(readLines(con=con,n=-1L,ok=TRUE, warn=FALSE,encoding='unknown')[3],destfile= dest_path)
```

if you can't read the file you get, try :

```
download.file(readLines(con=con,n=-1L,ok=TRUE, warn=FALSE,encoding='unknown')[3],destfile= dest_path, mode = "wb")
```

Comment: `con <- file("ABC1.iqy", "r", blocking = FALSE)`
is showing error " Error in file("ABC1.iqy", "r", blocking = FALSE) : 
  cannot open the connection"

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(openxlsx)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_IQY_File <- "D://file.iqy"
path_To_Excel_File <- gsub(pattern = ".iqy", replacement = ".xlsx", x = path_To_IQY_File)

xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_IQY_File)
xlWbk$SaveAs(path_To_Excel_File)

df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(path_To_Excel_File)
```

I have been able to use this approach for SharePoint lists.